# How to capture home button press? I need to emulate its functionality

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am having issues with my app returning to the foreground every time the user presses the back button. I believe this may be because there is a sound playing module that restarts the activity although this is just my hypothesis. However whenever I press the home (middle) button the app is sent to the background and everything works accordingly. I would like to emulate this functionality by capturing the back press event and handle it in a similar manner to the home button. While navigating the source, i've found the following handler in

`android/reactnativenavigation/layouts/SingleScreenLayout.java`

```
    @Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (handleBackInJs()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (stack.canPop()) {
        stack.pop(true, System.currentTimeMillis());
        EventBus.instance.post(new ScreenChangedEvent(stack.peek().getScreenParams()));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can understand at a glance what is being done however I am not very familiar with Java and don't want to introduce any bugs involving the native side of the app, could anyone kindly point out what I would need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to capture "the hardware back button" press not the home button right?
check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler) for the react-native way of doing it